# How to fix Sinatra returning NameError at/undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, sinatra, game-development

I'm trying to convert an RPG character sheet I created into a web page, but I'm having trouble.

This is the cardtricks.rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'
class Character
    def initialize(name, major_arcana, pentacles, wands, swords, cups, eyes, dress, hands)
        @name = name
        @major_arcana = major_arcana
        @pentacles = pentacles
        @wands = wands
        @swords = swords
        @cups = cups
        @eyes = eyes
        @dress = dress
        @hands = hands
    end
end

get '/' do
    erb :index, locals: {wizard_wizard: wizard_wizard}
end
```

This is the .erb file:

```
Begin!
<% 
#these are the decks we pull from!
$deck_of_52 = ["Ace of Spades", "Two of Spades", "Three of Spades", "Four of Spades", "Five of Spades", "Six of Spades", "Seven of Spades", "Eight of Spades", "Nine of Spades", "Ten of Spades", "Jack of Spades", "Queen of Spades", "King of Spades", "Ace of Hearts", "Two of Hearts", "Three of Hearts", "Four of Hearts", "Five of Hearts", "Six of Hearts", "Seven of Hearts", "Eight of Hearts", "Nine of Hearts", "Ten of Hearts", "Jack of Hearts", "Queen of Hearts", "King of Hearts", "Ace of Clubs", "Two of Clubs", "Three of Clubs", "Four of Clubs", "Five of Clubs", "Six of Clubs", "Seven of Clubs", "Eight of Clubs", "Nine of Clubs", "Ten of Clubs", "Jack of Clubs", "Queen of Clubs", "King of Clubs", "Ace of Diamonds", "Two of Diamonds", "Three of Diamonds", "Four of Diamonds", "Five of Diamonds", "Six of Diamonds", "Seven of Diamonds", "Eight of Diamonds", "Nine of Diamonds", "Ten of Diamonds", "Jack of Diamonds", "Queen of Diamonds", "King of Diamonds"]
def hand(x)
  $deck_of_52.sample(x)
end
$major_arcana = ["The Fool", "The Magician", "The High Priestess", "The Empress",  "The Emperor", " The Hierophant", "The Lovers", "The Chariot", "Fortitude", "The Hermit", "Wheel of Fortune", "Justice", "The Hanged Man", "Death", "Temperance", "The Devil", "The Tower", "The Star", "The Moon", "The Sun", "Judgement", "The World"]
def majorpull()
  $major_arcana.sample(1)
end
#this begins character creation!
def mainmenu 
    puts "Do you want to make a move, display your current character, or generate a new character?"
    choice = gets.chomp
        if ["make a move", "move"].include?(choice)
        puts $file_id.move
        puts mainmenu
        elsif ["display", "display my character"].include?(choice)
        puts $file_id.display
        puts mainmenu
        elsif ["generate", "generate a new character"].include?(choice)
        puts wizard_wizard
        else
        puts "Not sure what you meant.  Try again!"
        puts mainmenu
        end
end

def hand(x)
  $deck_of_52.sample(x)
end
def burn
        if (2..4).include?(@wands)
            puts hand(1)
        elsif (5..8).include?(@wands)
            puts hand(2)
        elsif (9..11).include?(@wands)
            puts hand(3)
        end
end
def tools
        if (2..4).include?(@pentacles)
            puts hand(1)
        elsif (5..8).include?(@pentacles)
            puts hand(2)
        elsif (9..11).include?(@pentacles)
            puts hand(3)
        end
end
def shock
        if (2..4).include?(@cups)
            puts hand(1)
        elsif (5..8).include?(@cups)
            puts hand(2)
        elsif (9..11).include?(@cups)
            puts hand(3)
        end
end
def commune
      if (2..4).include?(@swords)
            puts hand(1)
        elsif (5..8).include?(@swords)
            puts hand(2)
        elsif (9..11).include?(@swords)
            puts hand(3)
        end
 end
def display
        puts "My name is #{@name}, I bear the #{@major_arcana}.  I have #{@eyes} eyes, #{@dress} clothes, and #{@hands} hands.  My stats are #{@pentacles} of Pentacles, #{@wands} of Wands, #{@swords} of Swords, and #{@cups} of Cups."
 end
def move
        puts "What move do you want to take?  Burn and Brand, Commune with the Beyond, Tools of the Trade, or Shock and Awe?"
        input = gets.chomp.downcase
        if ["burn", "burn and brand"].include?(input)
            puts burn
        elsif ["shock", "shock and awe"].include?(input)
            puts shock
        elsif ["commune", "commune with the beyond"].include?(input)
            puts commune
        elsif ["tools", "tools of the trade"].include?(input)
            puts tools
        else
            puts "Sorry, that didn't make any sense to me.  Care to try again?"
            puts move
    end
    mainmenu
end
#this generates your character for Wizard World
def wizard_wizard
  puts "What is your name?"
  @playername = gets.chomp
  puts "Give an adjective for how your eyes look."
  @playereyes = gets.chomp
  puts "Give an adjective for how your clothes look."
  @playerdress = gets.chomp
  puts "Give an adjective for how your hands look."
  @playerhands = gets.chomp
  puts "We'll now draw your cards for you."
  @playermajor = majorpull
  w = rand(1..11)
  @playerwands = w
  c = rand(1..11)
  @playercups = c
  s = rand(1..11)
  @playerswords = s
  p = rand(1..11)
  @playerpentas = p
  puts "Name the file we'll save your character to!"
  $file_id = gets.chomp.to_i
  $file_id = Character.new(@playername, @playermajor, @playerpentas, @playerwands, @playerswords, @playercups, @playereyes, @playerdress, @playerhands)
  puts "Meet your new character!"
  $file_id.display
  mainmenu
end
puts wizard_wizard
%>
```

The error I got from Sinatra was:

```
undefined local variable or method `wizard_wizard' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x00007f6508de1470>
```

I tried giving `wizard_wizard` scopes (`@` or `$`) but that just results in more syntax errors.

Comment: Just FYI it's super nonstandard to put methods in your view file like this. I would start by refactoring this to use helpers, see http://sinatrarb.com/faq.html#helpview Also just another minor thing, you should consider using keyword arguments instead of positional args for the `Character#initialize` method .. keeping track of so many positional arguments can be a drag

Comment: Welcome to SO! As an additional FYI, grammar is important in SO. Think of the site as a series of encyclopedia entries of a question with answers to solve that question. As such, asking clearly and concisely is very important. People around the world refer to the questions to solve their problems so taking our time to write clearly helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`wizard_wizard` is undefined.

With sinatra, first, a ruby process starts, which will load general things and in your case also define the Character class. But then the execution flow starts with your definition of what should happen when calling `/`: Call `wizard_wizard`, give it with the key `:wizard_wizard` to the `locals` hash, and then call `erb` to interpret your index template. Only then the `wizard_wizard` function would be parsed.

Define your function in a separate file, require that file when you need it. Besides, requesting terminal input in a sinatra website template? That won't work. You do not need sinatra here - with it you have to adapt to the way web application work (HTML, input via forms, Javascript) while you seem to want to build a terminal application, which needs no framework at all.